# how to use javascript's onchange for @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

how to use onchange event for @Html.DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Tlitem.JobType, (SelectList)newSelectList, new { @class = "form-control js-select js-noFilter hidden", size = "2", @value = 0, Id = "JobType" + t ,@onchange="alert('hello');"});
```

above code doesn't work

Comment: So you want `onchange` or `onclick`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onchange event for html.dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056508/onchange-event-for-html-dropdownlist)

Comment: onchange @SᴇM  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `onclick` is, just change that to `onChange="javascript://whatever function you want()"`

for example

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Tlitem.JobType, (SelectList)newSelectList, new { @class = "form-control js-select js-noFilter hidden", size = "2", @value = 0, Id = "JobType" + t ,@onchange="javascript:onChangeFunction()";
```

Comment: Man, what a mess. Just to add a simple onChange event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("JobType").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

}
```

or if you're using JQuery:

```
$("#JobType").change(function() {
});
```